# Последовательная компиляция нескольких Solution в Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, dll, библиотеки, компиляция, компилятор

Дано:

1. Библиотека классов, дающая на выходе dll-библиотеку, лежит в локальном git-репозитории.
2. Приложение, использующее эту библиотеку, reference прописан прямо на папку Release библиотеки.

Вопрос: как автоматически при build/rebuild приложения перекомпилировать и библиотеку.

Пока что делаю через "событие перед сборкой", прописывая команды на сборку проекта туда через `devenv.exe /build Release %DllSolutionPath%`.
Как сделать лучше, удобнее?

Comment: А включить исходники библиотеки в Solution и поставить в старом коде вместо ссылок на бинарники ссылки на проекты не покатит?

Comment: Вам нужна пересборка либы даже если в ней код не менялся?

Comment: @VladD, после сборки по dll'ке проходится специальный инжектор, который её патчит через Mono.Cecil, боюсь, что это может помешать. Плюсом не хочется излишне усложнять свой проект, т.к. там в проекте библиотеки еще куча тестов, автогенерации документации, и т.д.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, для этого автоматизация и придумана, чтобы не работать "по памяти", имхо.

Comment: В студии можно указать последовательность сборки проектов внутри solution'а, при этом можно сказать что ваш exe, к примеру, зависит от dll. Тогда при изменении кодеса dll сначала соберется она, потом exe. Если я правильно понял - то что вам нужно?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, тогда такой вопрос. Если я в свой проект добавляю проект этой dll из локального репозитория, в нем изменений не происходит НИКАКИХ при добавлении? Если да, то это более чем приемлемо.

Comment: Вот за изменения не скажу, не интересовался этим вопросом. Файлы с исходниками не меняются определенно. Сейчас тогда в решение напишу...

Comment: @АлексейЕфремов: При добавлении в solution проекты не меняются (за исключением нескольких мелких случаев, наподобие нескольких проектов с одинаковым названием). В конце-концов, попробуйте, если будет что-то не так, можно откатиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такое.
В решение с exe добавьте проект с dll, потом ПКМ на проекте exe, ищите там "зависимости" и ставьте что exe зависит от dll. Тогда при изменении кода dll будет сначала собираться она, только потом exe.

Comment: Проверил, при добавлении существующего проекта не меняется ничего в каталоге самого проекта. Файл проекта также остается нетронутым.